# Signin buttons not getting rendered properly in my Android layout

Tags: android, google-signin, password-less

I created a signin page containing two buttons, one for Google signin and another for passwordless signin:

```
    <com.firebase.ui.auth.ui.phone.CountryListSpinner
        android:id="@+id/signInButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/FirebaseUI.Button.AccountChooser.GoogleButton"
        android:text="@string/fui_sign_in_with_google"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp" />

    <com.firebase.ui.auth.ui.phone.CountryListSpinner
        android:id="@+id/emailSignInButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/signInButton"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        style="@style/FirebaseUI.Button.AccountChooser.EmailButton"
        android:text="@string/fui_sign_in_with_email"
        tools:ignore="UnusedIds" />
```

However, when the layout is rendered, the buttons look like this:
[image]
instead of this:
[image]

Also, when I press either button, I get an error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.os.IBinder android.view.View.getApplicationWindowToken()' on a null object reference
```

I confirmed the button views are not null:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mFirebaseAnalytics = FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this);

    crashlytics = FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance();

    context = getApplicationContext();

    try {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
        Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.install_from_google_play), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        crashlytics.log("Crash on setContentView() in LoginActivity.java: " + ex.getLocalizedMessage());
        return;
    }

    Trace myTrace = FirebasePerformance.getInstance().newTrace("test_trace");
    myTrace.start();

    settings = getSharedPreferences(OPENCOMMENTS_SETTINGS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    editor = settings.edit();

    // Views
    findViewById(R.id.signInButton).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.emailSignInButton).setOnClickListener(this);
```

Anyone have an idea what's going on here? I'm running Android Studio Electric Eeel (2022.1.1 Canary 7) on a Linux computer and my project gradle file is the following:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.0-alpha07'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.9.5'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:perf-plugin:1.4.2'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was caused by a bug in com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:8.0.2. Once I reverted to 4.3.2, the problem went away.